# $R$ such that $R/J$ is artinian ($J$ is the Jacobson radical) and there exists an idempotent cannot be lifted modulo $J$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, idempotents, artinian

I know a few examples of rings and ideals such that there exists an idempotent cannot be lifted modulo the ideal (for instance, $\mathbb Z$ and $n\mathbb Z$).

My question is: is there a ring $R$ such that $R/J$ is artinian ($J$ denotes Jacobson radical of $R$) and there exists an idempotent $e$ that cannot be lifted modulo $J$?

I can't come up with this case. Maybe you know an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in other words, there are semilocal rings which aren't lift/rad.

One such example is the semilocalization of $\mathbb Z$ at the complement of $S=(2)\cup (3)$.

In this ring, $R/J(R)\cong F_1\times F_2$ for two fields.  Obviously this is artinian, and the nontrivial idempotents can't be lifted to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Here's the [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=24&L=26). Right now it only has that one confirmed example.

Comment: Well, thank you for the example! Can you please tell how can one show that $R/J(R)\cong F_1\times F_2$ and that nontrivials idempotents can't be lifted to $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: The only idempotents to lift to are $0$ and $1$, and obviously that's not gonna work for nontrivial idempotent lifting.  As for the first question, you can see the only maximal ideals are $(2)$ and $(3)$ and their intersection is the Jacobson radical: so $R/J(R)\cong R/(2)\times R/(3)$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's all clear.